# Getting rid of default validation messages for required fields in edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9gTB.png)I'm looking for some solution for getting rid of default validation messages for required fields in edge.

I already solved this problem in chrome, and I disappeared the red border.
I have this HTML code:

```
<div>
  <span>{{'First_Name' | translate}}</span>
  <span class="required-mark pc-only">*</span>
  <input name="fname" ng-model="$ctrl.formData.firstName" ng-change="$ctrl.updateField('firstName')" placeholder="{{'First_Name' | translate}}*" ng-focus="fnameVisited=true; fnameFocus=true;" ng-blur="fnameFocus=false;" ng-pattern="/^[\x20-\x2F\x3A-\x3B\x41-\x7E]*$/" required ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="40" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(' ')"/>
  <div ng-messages="member1.fname.$error" ng-if="(fnameVisited && !fnameFocus) || $ctrl.formSubmitted">
    <div ng-message="minlength" class="error-message">{{ 'err_length' | translate }}</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength" class="error-message">{{ 'err_length' | translate }}</div>
    <div ng-message="required" class="error-message">{{ 'err_required' | translate}}</div>
    <div ng-message="pattern" class="error-message">{{ 'err_english' | translate}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css code:

```
  input, select {
    width: 336px;
    height: 35px;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 12px;
    border: 1px solid $c-border-gray-1;
    font-family: 'open sans';
    background-color: $c-white;
    color: $c-gray-input-text;
  }

  input::placeholder {
    color: $c-white;
  }

  input:required:invalid {
    outline: none;
  }

  textarea:required:invalid {
    outline: none;
  }
```

thanks!!

Comment: If all of this is inside a `form`, you can just add `novalidate`: i.e. `<form novalidate>`.

Comment: thanks :) it solves it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `required` attribute from the field. I mean since you aren't altering the error message itself, why make the field required.

Update

```
<form action="hey.php" id="hi">
<input id="required" onblur="check()">

</form>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("required");
var y=document.getElementById("form");

function check()
{
if(x.value=='')
{
alert('please fill that field');
y.acton="#";
}
}




</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I need the required for posting my custom error msg under the field.

Comment: I dont know how to do that with only css but you can do something like that with javascript...should I show you the code to do that?